# In selenium webdriver, verify that all products are sorted by name

Tags: selenium, webdriver

In Selenium WebDriver, if I select drop down value by 'name' then how do I verify that all products are sorted by name?

This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Magneto
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        WebDriver d1 = new FirefoxDriver();
        d1.navigate().to("http://live.guru99.com/index.php/");
        d1.manage().window().maximize();
        if (d1.getTitle().equals("Home page")) {
            System.out.println("title matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("title not matched expected title is "
                + d1.getTitle());
        }
        d1.findElement(By.xpath("//nav[@id='nav']/ol/li[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (d1.getTitle().equals("Mobile")) {
            System.out.println("title matched");
        } else {
            System.out.println("title not matched expected title is "
                + d1.getTitle());
        }
        Select s1 = new Select(d1.findElement(By.xpath("//html[@id='top']/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select")));
        s1.selectByVisibleText("Name");}}
```

Comment: This community is here to help you, but not to complete your tasks. Please provide more information about what you've done so far and where you got stuck.

Comment: Can you please post your code or which website your are trying to do it. So that it will be easy for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following code to your main method

```
//create an LinkedList instead of arraylist because it preserves insertion order

List<WebElement> products_Webelement = new LinkedList<WebElement>();

//store the products (web elements) into the linkedlist

products_Webelement = d1.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@id, 'product-collection-image')]"));

//create another linked list of type string to store image title

LinkedList<String> product_names =  new LinkedList<String>();

//loop through all the elements of the product_webelement list get it title and store it into the product_names list

for(int i=0;i<products_Webelement.size();i++){

    String s = products_Webelement.get(i).getAttribute("alt");

    product_names.add(s);

}

//send the list to chkalphabetical_order method to check if the elements in the list are in alphabetical order    

boolean result = chkalphabetical_order(product_names);


//print the result    

System.out.println(result);
```

In the method chkalphabetical_order we check if the elements are in alphabetical order by using compareTo method because string class in java implements Comparable and the comparison will be done by using the strings natural ordering.This method will return true if the elements are in alphabetical order else return false

```
    public static boolean chkalphabetical_order(LinkedList<String> product_names){

    String previous = ""; // empty string

    for (final String current: product_names) {
        if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
            return false;
        previous = current;
    }

    return true;

    }
```

Hope this helps you . I tested the above code it was working perfectly.If you have any doubts kindly get back

Answer (score 1):

```
String sortElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[1]//a[@class=\"product-image\"]")).getAttribute("title");
Assert.assertEquals(sortElement, "IPhone");
sortElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[2]//a[@class=\"product-image\"]")).getAttribute("title");
Assert.assertEquals(sortElement, "Samsung Galaxy");
sortElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[3]//a[@class=\"product-image\"]")).getAttribute("title");
Assert.assertEquals(sortElement, "Xperia");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario in which i had to verify the sorted menu

```
try{
        List<WebElement> lst = driver.findElements(By
                .xpath(".//*[@id='global-wrapper']/nav/ul/li"));
        String[] str = new String[lst.size()];
        String[] ORGstr = new String[lst.size()];

    int i = 0;
    int l = 0;
    for (WebElement ele1 : lst) {
        if (ele1.getText() != null)
            ORGstr[l] = ele1.getText();
        l++;
    }

    for (WebElement ele : lst) {
        if (ele.getText() != null)
            str[i] = ele.getText();
        i++;
    }

    for (int b = 0; b < str.length; b++) {

        for (int j = b + 1; j < str.length; j++) {
            if (str[b].compareTo(str[j]) > 0) {
                String temp = str[b];
                str[b] = str[j];
                str[j] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
    int o = 1;
    int s = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < str.length; k++) {
        //System.out.println("Sorted Order " + str[s] + " ");
        //System.out.println("Original Order " + ORGstr[o] + " ");
        if (!(str[s].equalsIgnoreCase("Dashboard"))) {
            if (str[s].equalsIgnoreCase(ORGstr[o])) {
                assertEquals(str[s], ORGstr[o]);
                o++;
                log.debug("verified dashboard menu is sorted");
            } else {

                Assert.fail();
            }
        }
        s++;

    }

    }catch(Exception e){

        ErrorLog.fatal("Error: Element not located in menu");   
    }
```

In my code i had to skip a menu item called dashboard i wrote it according to my requirement you can change accordingly!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> li=new LinkedList<>(obj.findElements(By.xpath("//h2[@class='product-name']/a")));    
        LinkedList<String> pn=new LinkedList<String>();    
        for(int i=0;i<li.size();i++)    
        {    
             //just displaying the product names    
            //System.out.println(li.get(i).getText());    
            pn.add(li.get(i).getText());    
        }    
        boolean result = comp_order(pn);    

you need to add one more method    

//alphabetical order checking    
    public static boolean comp_order(LinkedList<String> pn)    
    {           
        String prev=""; // empty string    
        for (final String cur: pn)    
        {    
            if (cur.compareTo(prev) < 0)    
            {      
                return false;     
            }    
            prev=cur;    
        }    
        return true;    
        }    

i did nothing just improved previous solution its working
```

Answer (score 0):

This Sorting method fails if Products' names start with both Lowercase letters and Uppercase Letters.

if you run, and check

```
public class Testing
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String name1= "pro";
        String name2= "TestPro";
        int tmp=name2.compareTo(name1);
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
} 
Output: -28
```

Although, we were expecting it to return some positive integer.

So, to get rid of this problem we need to convert all names to lowercase and then Check if they are sorted or not?

Here is how i did it, My code has some other functions as well to which you can ignore.

```
public class SortingTest 
{
    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public static void AnchorTags() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver=new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.get("http://xyz21314131.co");

        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Ascending Order")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement Row=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//* [@id='content']/div/div[2]"));
        List<WebElement> Anchortags=Row.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

        //Linked List to Store ProductNames
        LinkedList<String> productNames=new LinkedList<String>();

        int size=Anchortags.size();

        for(WebElement temp:Anchortags)
        {
            String sTemp=temp.getText();
          //Important
           **// to remove extra spaces and to Lowercase Every product name**
            productNames.add(sTemp.toLowerCase().trim());           
        }
        System.out.println(productNames);


        //Check SortedOr NOt?

        Boolean num=checkDescendingOrder(productNames);
        System.out.println("boolean value"+ num);
        if(num==true)
        {

            System.out.println("Products names are Sorted in ascending Order");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Products names are not Sorted in ascending Order");
            }
        System.out.println("New List:--"+productNames);
        System.out.println("Size is " + size);
    }

public static boolean checkAscendingOrder(LinkedList<String> Names)
{
    String previous = ""; // empty string

    for (String current: Names) {
        if (current.compareTo(previous) < 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    return true;
    }   
}
```